# Adding character in matrix in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I import csv by.

```
data<-read.csv('test.csv')
```

and then data has value

```
> data
  name a b c d
1    a 1 2 1 1
2    b 2 2 2 4
```

now i wish to add row at the bottom of data so,I add

```
results <- c('aa',2,3,4,5)
data[nrow(data)+1,]<-results
```

But it cause me warring and character value is not inserted.

```
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "aa") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

and data has value =

```
> data
  name a b c d
1    a 1 2 1 1
2    b 2 2 2 4
3 <NA> 2 3 4 5
```

but i want to have

```
> data
  name a b c d
1    a 1 2 1 1
2    b 2 2 2 4
3    aa 2 3 4 5
```

I am new in R and have tried for the ans for many hours so any help will be appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: Try not to have factor variables in your data frame and your code will work. This simple example will show the difference `dt =  data.frame(x=c("A","B"),
                 y=1:2, stringsAsFactors = T);
dt[3,] = c("C",3);

dt =  data.frame(x=c("A","B"),
                 y=1:2, stringsAsFactors = F);
dt[3,] = c("C",3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
data <- read.csv('test.csv', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

In a short explanation, read.csv treat every character column as a factor by default. Factor are a special class of data that can only take a few values determined at its creation.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following:(I am putting data in here you could use `read.csv`)

```
dat <- read.table(text = "name a b c d
1    a 1 2 1 1
2    b 2 2 2 4",
header = TRUE,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
dat
results <- c('aa',2,3,4,5)
rbind(dat,results)
```

Output(without using `stringAsFactors = FALSE`):

```
  name a b c d
1    a 1 2 1 1
2    b 2 2 2 4
3 <NA> 2 3 4 5
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = "aa") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

Output without warning message:

```
  name a b c d
1    a 1 2 1 1
2    b 2 2 2 4
3   aa 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems here:

1. The first column is a factor so you can only add levels that that factor has.
2. If `c(...)` is used with a mix of characters and numerics the result is character.
3. `data` is a data.frame, not a matrix -- the question incorrectly states it is a matrix.  (If it were a matrix then it would be a character matrix since you can't mix character and numeric in a matrix.)

To fix these problems use `as.is = TRUE` in `read.csv` and use `list` instead of `c`:

```
data <- read.csv("test.csv", as.is = TRUE)
data[nrow(data) + 1, ] <- list('aa',2,3,4,5)
```

giving:

```
> data
  name a b c d
1    a 1 2 1 1
2    b 2 2 2 4
3   aa 2 3 4 5
```

### Note

The file in reproducible form is generated from:

```
Lines <- "name a b c d
1    a 1 2 1 1
2    b 2 2 2 4
"
temp <- read.table(text = Lines, as.is = TRUE)
write.csv(temp, "test.csv", row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Include 'aa' as one of the `levels` and it should work with the OP's `factor` column.  Also, as `list` can hold different `type` instead of a vector (formed with `c`), assign the next row with a `list` as input

```
levels(data$name) <- c(levels(data$name), 'aa')
data[nrow(data) +1,] <- list('aa', 2, 3, 4, 5)
data
#  name a b c d
#1    a 1 2 1 1
#2    b 2 2 2 4
#3   aa 2 3 4 5
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(name = structure(1:2, .Label = c("a", "b"),
 class = "factor"), 
a = 1:2, b = c(2L, 2L), c = 1:2, d = c(1L, 4L)), .Names = c("name", 
 "a", "b", "c", "d"), row.names = c("1", "2"), class = "data.frame")
```